# Load Xml file in ListView and edit some values

Tags: xml, xamarin.android, android-listview

I am very new in C# and Xamarin at all. First of all, I would like to read this example XMl file and show in ListView. Then, I must edit some value from this xml. Could anybody give me example how can I do it?

```
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>French Toast</name>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
        <calories>600</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
        <calories>950</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Convert XML AS Classes**

In Visual Studio> Edit Menu> Paste Special> Paste XML As Classes

```
// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class breakfast_menu
{

    private breakfast_menuFood[] foodField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("food")]
    public breakfast_menuFood[] food
    {
        get
        {
            return this.foodField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.foodField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class breakfast_menuFood
{

    private string nameField;

    private string priceField;

    private string descriptionField;

    private ushort caloriesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string price
    {
        get
        {
            return this.priceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.priceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort calories
    {
        get
        {
            return this.caloriesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.caloriesField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Convert the XML AS list** Get the list from XML file and binding to the listview.

**>Xamarin.Forms:** read from the `Embedded resource`

```
 var list = new List<breakfast_menuFood>();
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "App1.breakfast2.xml";
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<breakfast_menu>));

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(breakfast_menu));
            var breakfast = (breakfast_menu)serializer2.Deserialize(reader);
            foreach (var item in breakfast.food)
            {
                list.Add(new breakfast_menuFood
                {
                    calories = item.calories,
                    description = item.description,
                    name = item.name,
                    price = item.price
                });
            }
        }
```

**>Xamarin.Android:** read from Assets folder.

```
 using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("breakfast.xml")))
            {
                //xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();                

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(breakfast_menu));
                var school = (breakfast_menu)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);

                var list = new List<breakfast_menuFood>();

                foreach (var item in school.food)
                {
                    list.Add(new breakfast_menuFood
                    {
                        calories = item.calories,
                        description = item.description,
                        name = item.name,
                        price = item.price
                    });
                }
            }
```

[image]